# Choosing Geographic Information Systems or Earth Science Stack Exchange to ask Geographic questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask here first because I want to know well okay I check out the list of question here and many are about Geographic but in programming my question is could I ask about Geographic general here?

For example, about  any area of the world, or not?

Sorry if my question is poor or something similar and I am not expert in this area but I am start in this area and I would like to ask well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GIS StackExchange is a place for questions about "GIS, Remote Sensing, Photogrammetry, Geodesy and Surveying, as well as Programming/Databases specific to the aforementioned." GIS stands for Geographic Information System, which is a *type of computer software* for dealing with geographic data.

Earth Science StackExchange is a place for questions about "geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences."

**Questions about geography would be more appropriate to Earth Science StackExchange.**

If you're still not sure where to ask, my advice is to just pick a site and ask your question. If the site users think it should be on a different site, they will [politely](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) say so.